# Can there be separate compilation units within one Scala project?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros

I am currently trying to grasp the concept of macros in Scala. Macros cannot be used in the compilation unit in which they were defined.

To tackle this issue, I did it like [@adamw](https://github.com/adamw/) in [this](https://github.com/adamw/scala-macro-debug/blob/master/project/Build.scala) example, i.e., I used sbt to create a project containing two sub-projects -- one containing the macros, the other containing the examples that make use of the macros.

However, while this works, I feel like it's not a clean approach. After all, shouldn't macros be part of the project that they belong to logically? Therefore, is it possible to have the macros' definitions as well as the code that uses them located in the same project, while setting up separate compilation units within that one sbt project?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There has been discussion of using a `Macro` config scope that would add an additional `macro:compile` task.

This would allow you to place macro sources into `src/macro/scala` and make `macro:compile` a dependency for `compile`.

With such a config scope, you could have macros and regular sources in the same project. However, this isn't a default setup in sbt and would be something you would have to add yourself. I forget the exact incantation required.